# touchesBegan @ multitask

Tags: objective-c, multitasking, ios4

Is it possible to access to the touchesBegan event while application is running in background in iPhoneOS 4.0 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When the app is in background, no views of the app is visibile, so you can't touch it, and `touchesBegan` etc. won't be fired.